# How to isolate specific strings from a string of variable size, how to translate exponents

Tags: c#, string

I am using an API that returns a simple string value. I want to be able to take the number result, including the exponential values, and put them on their corresponding layer of an array, but I am not sure how to isolate that number.

This is what the result looks like.
I don't want to use JSON.

I'm thinking a method using the .Split method, but I don't know how to parse the number or the exponents

```
{
    "faceRectangle": {
        "left": 68,
        "top": 97,
        "width": 64,
        "height": 97
    },
    "scores": {
        "anger": 0.00300731952,
        "contempt": 5.14648448E-08,
        "disgust": 9.180124E-06,
        "fear": 0.0001912825,
        "happiness": 0.9875571,
        "neutral": 0.0009861537,
        "sadness": 1.889955E-05,
        "surprise": 0.008229999
    }
}
```

Comment: What number is "that number"? What have you tried?

Comment: You're looking for a JSON parser.

Comment: The format of the data returned by this API is JSON. It's a structured format that can be easily parsed by almost any programming framework. There exists libraries in .NET that can parse JSON and convert them into strongly typed objects from which it's easy to extract values - I suggest you find one and follow its directions to make use of it. An easy way to find libraries related to what you want to do is to go to [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/), search for what you want (JSON) and then pick a library that has a lot of downloads and then research that library to make sure it's well supported

Comment: take a look there: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Answer (score 0):

Cast your JSON string to the `JObject` instance from Newtonsoft and then 
get properties by name **scores** or **faceRectangle**, then select what exact number you want using property name.

Answer (score 0):

Parse your JSON object, then iterate it, check if it's number and compute.

```
var json_object = (dynamic) null;

dynamic json_object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json_string);

foreach (var item in json_object)
{
    if (double.TryParse(item, out num))
    {
        // It's a number, do whatever you want with it!
    }
}
```